# Profiles automatically adding to Groups

Tags: profile, groups

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.22 on Wordpress.

In the profile creation advanced settings, we have the option of automatically adding the person to a specific group when they fill out the profile form.

I have two groups, Donors and Members.  Members get access to restricted areas, while donors do not.

My dilemma is, if someone who already has a membership account decides to submit a separate donation, is he then going to be removed from the Membership group and placed in the Donors group?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They should be just added to the Donor group. This should not effect the existing group memberships.